# MySQL recursive cycle detection procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion, graph

I have the following procedure which is meant to detect cycles in an undirected graph taking an edge (singleedge) and an edge set (edgeset). There are two more arguments, left_set(which is meant to store necessary edges to be passed into recursions) and cyclic( which is a boolean value that ultimately determines whether or not the graph was cyclic.

For some reason, the detection does not work past the first recursion. Here is the code with comments explaining the details:

**THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS WERE IMPLEMENTED BY ME IN MYSQL (to avoid confusion):**

-concat_set(): returns the concatenation of two sets accounting for misplaced ',' in case of an empty set

-remove_first(): removes the first member from set

-get_left_node()/get_right_node: returns nodes of edges, the delimiter between the edges is ':' so an edge looks like this '12:15'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `is_cyclic`(
IN `singleedge` VARCHAR(15), 
IN `edgeset` VARCHAR(1024), 
IN 'left_set' VARCHAR(512), 
OUT `cyclic` BOOLEAN)

BEGIN
DECLARE se_left VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE es_left VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE se_right VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE es_right VARCHAR(5);
Call get_left_node(singleedge, se_left);
Call get_left_node(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edgeset, ',', 1), es_left);
Call get_right_node(singleedge, se_right);
Call get_right_node(SUBSTRING_INDEX(edgeset, ',', 1), es_right);



--is edgeset emptY?
    IF LENGTH(edgeset)= 0 AND LENGTH(left_set) = 0 THEN
        BEGIN

            SET cyclic= false;

        END;    

--are singeeledge and first edge in edgeset the same?        
    ELSEIF ((se_left = es_left
        OR se_left= es_right)
        AND( se_right = es_left
        OR se_right = es_right)) THEN
                    BEGIN
            set cyclic= true;
                        END;


--do singleedge and first edge in edgeset share any vertices?       
    ELSEIF se_left = es_left 
        OR se_left= es_right
        OR se_right = es_left
        OR se_right = es_right
        THEN
        --check for all possiblities
            BEGIN

                --if left vertex of singleedge and left vertex of current edge in front of edgeset are the same               
                IF se_left=es_left THEN
                                    BEGIN
                                    --test if the edge of combined uncommon vertices (forming concat(se_right,':',es_right)) exists in the remaining edgeset concatanated with the left_set
                                    CALL is_cyclic(concat(se_right,':',es_right),concat_set(left_set,remove_first(edgeset)), '', cyclic);
                                    --if the recursion returns cyclic=false, then remove the considered edge from edgeset and continue trying to match the original singleedge with the rest of edgeset
                                     IF cyclic=false THEN
                                        CALL is_cyclic(singleedge, remove_first(edgeset), left_set, cyclic);
                                      END IF;
                                     END;
                ELSEIF se_left= es_right THEN
                                    BEGIN
                                    CALL is_cyclic(concat(se_right,':',es_left), concat_set(left_set, remove_first(edgeset)), '', cyclic);
                                    IF cyclic=false THEN
                                        CALL is_cyclic(singleedge, remove_first(edgeset), left_set, cyclic);
                                     END IF;
                                     END;
                ELSEIF se_right=es_left THEN
                                    BEGIN
                                    CALL is_cyclic(concat(se_left,':',es_right), concat_set(left_set, remove_first(edgeset)), '', cyclic);
                                    IF cyclic=false THEN
                                        CALL is_cyclic(singleedge, remove_first(edgeset), left_set, cyclic);
                                    END IF;
                                    END;
                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                    CALL is_cyclic(concat(se_left,':',es_left), concat_set(left_set, remove_first(edgeset)), '', cyclic);
                                    IF cyclic=false THEN
                                        CALL is_cyclic(singleedge, remove_first(edgeset), left_set, cyclic);
                                    END IF;  
                                      END;
                                END IF;


            END;    


        ELSE
            BEGIN
                --if the current edge being considered from the edgeset does not contain any vertex in common with singleedge, set it aside into left_set and call is_cyclic recurisvely with the edge removed
                SET left_set = concat_set(left_set, SUBSTRING_INDEX(edgeset, ',', 1));
                CALL is_cyclic(singleedge, remove_first(edgeset), left_set, cyclic);
                END;

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: I would just unwind the recursion into a loop. It might make the code a little uglier, but it's already pretty ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset this mysql variable: max_sp_recursion_depth, thread_stack

```
SET SESSION max_sp_recursion_depth = 10;
SET SESSION thread_stack = 250000;
```

After executing above command call your procedure. Execute both statement serially. 
Increase the size of **thread_stack** variable as per your requirement.

Comment: This actually worked, I was setting the recursion depth like this before: `SET GLOBAL max_sp_recursion_depth = 150; ` is there any difference between the two? I also get the following error when checking for cycles on larger sets: `#1436 - Thread stack overrun ` Should I manually specify a larger stack or is it better to fix the code and prevent this?

Comment: Global keyword reset the variable globally means it resets by 150 until youe mysql service restarts. And it's not neccessary that you have toreset this variable globally, so instead of this you can reset that variable per session.

Comment: I never got the code I posted working without it throwing the `Thread stack overrun` error.